# android imageview.setBackgroundResource() doesn't work

Tags: java, android, image, mobile, imageview

I have an **imageview that should be changed on click**

```
public class Settings extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
     private ImageView im1;
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.settings);
         im1 = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.imageView1 );
         im1.setOnClickListener(this);
     }
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v)
     {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if (v == im1 )
         {
             Log.d("test", "hey!");
             v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img1);
         }
     }
}
```

**when clicked the method runs and prints out "hey!" but the image won't change?**

**EDIT**: forgot to mention that `imageview` contains another image provided by xml layout file

Comment: is the image that your imageview contains transparent ? because the background is, well, in the background

Answer (score 50, accepted):

By convention, you should be using `setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);` (or `setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img1));`) instead of `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img1);`.

Answer (score 4):

```
  ImageView i = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.imageView1 );
  i.setImageResource(R.id.logo);

   or

  i.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

Now, you can use like below,

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.img1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This In API 25

```
imgSchedule.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circle_image_selected));
```

Answer (score 0):

Its no convention that setimageResource() should be used.
Both the APIs can be used.

Also, in  your case, it just looks like the case of out of sync resources.