# Set imageview background on button click?

Tags: android, resources, imageview, setbackground

lets say I have a timer activity. Theres an image view that displays a number of 0 - 9(these are viewed as images, NOT text).
eg. the images names are clock_0, clock_1, clock_2...clock_9.
There is a plus and minus button that should change a counter(to pick the image). If current image is clock_0, pressing the plus button will change the view to clock_1 etc. How do I do this efficiently?

EDIT
Heres what I tried to do;
set an int[],

```
int[] clockResource = new int[10];
    clockResource[0] = R.drawable.clock_0;
    clockResource[1] = R.drawable.clock_1;
    clockResource[2] = R.drawable.clock_2;
    clockResource[3] = R.drawable.clock_3;
    clockResource[4] = R.drawable.clock_4;
    clockResource[5] = R.drawable.clock_5;
    clockResource[6] = R.drawable.clock_6;
    clockResource[7] = R.drawable.clock_7;
    clockResource[8] = R.drawable.clock_8;
    clockResource[9] = R.drawable.clock_9;
```

assign an onclicklistener for the addbutton

```
case R.id.addMin:
        if (addMin.isEnabled()) {
            if (mintwo < 9) {
                mintwo++;
            } else if (mintwo == 9) {
                minone++;
                mintwo = 0;
            }
            min2.setBackgroundResource(clockResource[mintwo]);
            min1.setBackgroundResource(clockResource[minone]);
        }
```

Comment: have you tried any code then please paste it too.

Comment: have you any orblem by using setBackgroundResource

Comment: ok whats the issue? or come to my room will discuss http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10629/agarwal

Comment: @Agarwal when i click on the button, i get this error,
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/33331786/TIMER/log.txt

Comment: line 75 is "min2.setBackgroundResource(clockResource[mintwo]);"

Answer (score 0):

Since they're ImageViews, use [setImageDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) or [setImageResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29) instead.

[Related SO-question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592911/android-imageview-setbackgroundresource-doesnt-work)

Comment: this is the correct answer . also , consider using getidentifier instead of initializing the array of ids (clockResource) one id after another . much easier to use a loop for this. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
case R.id.addMin:
        if (addMin.isEnabled()) {
            if (mintwo < 9) {
                mintwo++;
            } else if (mintwo == 9) {
                minone++;
                mintwo = 0;
            }
            min2.setImageResource(clockResource[mintwo]);  //updated
            min1.setImageResource(clockResource[minone]);  //updated
        }
```