# change background by java

Tags: java, android

```
 package com.bzgames.minecraftbz;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;


 public class GameView extends View implements Runnable {

        private static final long INTERVAL = 10;
        private boolean running;

        public GameView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            Thread minhaThread = new Thread(this);
            minhaThread.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
            minhaThread.start();

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (running){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Erro", e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        }
        public void release(){
            running = false;
        }

 }
```

How do I change the background layout with Java? I tried using the bitmap but I am unable to change the background of the layout the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this 3 ways, as far as I know, programatically:

1- With canvas and a repaint method.

2- With big bitmaps:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

3- Using methods like "setImageResource(...)"

[android imageview.setBackgroundResource() doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592911/android-imageview-setbackgroundresource-doesnt-work?answertab=active#tab-top)

But as you're dealing with games, I suggest you use Canvas or some other framework that will give you more support to manipulate graphic elements.

Boa sorte!