# android change image onclick imageviev

Tags: android, image, imageview, onclicklistener

How can I change Image of an `Imageview`?

I want to get the image associated; if it is `img1` I want set the image to `img2`, if it is `img2` I want to set the image to `img2`.

Comment: use `ImageView.setTag()` and `ImageView.getTag()` to check which image is currently associated with ImageView before change ImageView src

Comment: if it is `img2`, why do you want to "set the image" to `img2`? I think you have a typo their.

Comment: Yes, if it is img2 then img1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first set the tag of imageview in xml to 1

```
final ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(imageview.getTag().toString()) == 1) {
                imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2);

                imageview.setTag(2);

            } else {
                imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);
                imageview.setTag(1);

            }

        }
});
```

Comment: So, how can I initialize the tag before setonclicklistener?

Comment: Excuse me..In xml what do I write? android:tag='1'?

Comment: cannot refer to a non final variable imageview inside an inner class defined in a different method

Comment: declare imageview as final

Comment: I've written ImageView imageview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1); before the setonclicklistener...it is correct?

Comment: final ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

Comment: try using `imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);` instead of `imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2);`
Taken from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592911/android-imageview-setbackgroundresource-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `ImageView.setTag()` and `ImageView.getTag()`.It checks if the image is associated with the Image view as @ρяσѕρєя K mentioned in comment.

`There are two version of setTag one which takes object as an argument and other takes key and object as an argument`