# Change set of Image resource on Button click in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have there sets of drawable in int array. Is it possible to change the image resource of the image view in the fragment on button click? for example i have there a method onclicklistener for button benefit_babies... i want to set the image resource into the int array benefitBaby on click of the button.

InformationTab fragment

```
package com.example.aldrinjohn.sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Aldrin John on 3/20/2017.
 */

public class InformationTab extends Fragment{
    ViewPager viewPager;
    CustomSwipeAdapter adapter;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.informationtab, container, false);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        adapter = new CustomSwipeAdapter(this.getActivity());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


        return rootView;

    }

}
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/trivia"
        android:text="BreastFeeding Trivia"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/benefit_babies"
        android:text="Benefits to Babies"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/storing"
        android:text="Storing Breastmilk"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/pump"
            android:text="How to Pump Breastmilk"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/benefit_mother"
            android:text="Benefits to Mothers"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tips"
            android:text="Tips and Information"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image_view"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

JAVA Code:

```
package com.example.aldrinjohn.sample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.Container;

/**
 * Created by Aldrin John on 3/26/2017.
 */

public class CustomSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements View.OnClickListener{
    private int[] trivia = {R.drawable.c1,R.drawable.c2,R.drawable.c3,R.drawable.c4, R.drawable.c5,R.drawable.c6};
    private int[] benefitBaby = {R.drawable.c7,R.drawable.c8,R.drawable.c9};
    private int[] benefitMother = {R.drawable.c91,R.drawable.c92};
    private int[] info = {R.drawable.a1,R.drawable.a2,R.drawable.a3,R.drawable.a4,R.drawable.a5,R.drawable.a6,R.drawable.a7,
                            R.drawable.a8,R.drawable.a9,R.drawable.a91,R.drawable.a92};
    private int[] storing = {R.drawable.b1,R.drawable.b2,R.drawable.b3,R.drawable.b4};
    private Context ctx;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    Button btnbenefitB;

    public CustomSwipeAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return trivia.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view==(LinearLayout)object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position){
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout,container,false);
        btnbenefitB = (Button)item_view.findViewById(R.id.benefit_babies);
        btnbenefitB.setOnClickListener(this);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(trivia[position]);
        container.addView(item_view);

        return item_view;
    }
@Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object){
        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    }


    public int getCount(int[] x) {
        return x.length - 1;
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.benefit_babies:

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android change image onclick imageviev](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957031/android-change-image-onclick-imageviev)

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev not really sir. that just set an image. while what I'm trying to ask is to initialize a new SET of drawable image on button click.

Answer (score 1):

`imageview.setImageResource(id)` where `id` is in your `int` array. See the [documentation for `ImageView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)) for details. It is the same as you have in your code just in the `onClick()` handler.

> **setImageResource**
>
> void setImageResource (int resId)
>
> Sets a drawable as the content of this ImageView.
>
> This does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can cause a latency hiccup. If that's a concern, consider using setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) or setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap) and BitmapFactory instead.

Comment: how to code that in button onclick? I tried 

ImageView imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image_view); 
imageView.setImageResource(benefitBaby[0]); I tried value 0-2 but still crashing for it say that it returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone thanks for the help. I solved it by using view page adapter. Every onclick button I will change the adapter. Thank you!!